# Idiom for dividing something into steps instead of doing it all at once

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I initially thought it's something like "pacing it out", but after googling it that doesn't seem to be the case.

Example:

> You have a whole bunch of photos and you post them one a day instead
>   of dumping them all at once.

Comment: You could often use [***drip feed***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/drip-feed) *- to supply (information) constantly but in small amounts* in such situations, but I'm not sure that would work in your *exact* context.

Comment: Possibly to do things **piecemeal**. Also there is the phrase "to take things **one step at a time**".

Comment: You might be thinking of the phrase "to space things out" or "spacing things out," instead of "pacing it [things] out." As in, "I plan to space out my mailings, one a day, over the next six months."

Comment: To "take things one step at a time" is probably the most used, as well as, straight forward answer.

Comment: Do *something* ***little by little, bit by bit***.

Comment: I have this ***sort out***, going to post 1 photo daily!

Answer (score 4):

You may be thinking of "***pace yourself***":

> to try not to do things too quickly so that you have enough energy to be able to complete your task successfully:
>   *Pacing yourself and setting achievable goals are the keys to success in this business.*
>   <sub>*from [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pace#translations)*</sub>

Comment: This, coupled with @rhetorician's suggestion, seems a good explanation.

Answer (score 3):

At least in computing, there is `divide and conquer`.

Wiktionary:

> **[divide and conquer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/divide_and_conquer)**
>   (*computing*) An algorithm design technique applied to various algorithms, such as quicksort, that solve
>   a problem by splitting it recursively into smaller problems until all
>   of the remaining problems are trivial.

Comment: It's a great idiom. The area of application has obviously been broadened in recent years, as your quote shows. I don't think it would be standardly used for spacing out mailshots, though.

Answer (score 2):

Not an idiomatic phrase but a single word which may work here is: ***instalments***.
Yet another word which may work is: ***piecemeal***.

ODO:

> **[instalment](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/instalment)**.  (*US* **installment**)
>
> *NOUN*
>
> **2.** Any of several parts of something which are published, broadcast, or made public in sequence at intervals.
>
> ‘A summary of the story will be published in instalments in NZine.’
>
> **[piecemeal](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/piecemeal)**
>
> *ADJECTIVE & ADVERB*
>
> Characterized by unsystematic partial measures taken over a period of
> time.
>
> [as adjective] ‘the village is slowly being killed off by piecemeal
> development’
>
> [as adverb] ‘many organizations have been built up piecemeal’

Answer (score 0):

I often use "little steps for little feet."   However, this idiom suggests breaking a problem into small, manageable steps rather than your second-level meaning of "spread the task over time" for some reason other than difficulty.

Perhaps something as simple as "serial distribution" would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Rhetorician wrote in [a comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/397682/idiom-for-dividing-something-into-steps-instead-of-doing-it-all-at-once#comment944259_397682):

> You might be thinking of the phrase "to space things out" or "spacing things out," instead of "pacing it [things] out." As in, "I plan to space out my mailings, one a day, over the next six months."

Answer (score -1):

In the software development world, we `iterate` on the development of a solution until it satisfies our customers' requirements; but this almost always connotes a feedback loop.

For example, you might iterate the process of posting photos by posting some photos each week, and every week you would adjust which photos are selected based on feedback from the previous week's reviews.

Without feedback, the word I'd consider would be to `trickle` the release of the photos.

Comment: But doesn't iterate in this context mean you do a quick completion, correct to better version, correct again? This is different from building successive functionalities one after another, which is what I would regard as steps.

Comment: @David, iteration in software engineering is to quickly develop a working feature, develop another, and another, until you have enough features to build a minimum viable product that you then ship. After that, each iteration adds a new minor piece of working functionality to the product.  "Correct to better version, correct again" implies starting with a steaming pile of bugs and entering an endless loop of bug fixing; even though many product teams are certainly behaving this way, that's definitely not the best practice, and that's never supposed to be the plan.